# Django forms to restrict chinese characters

Tags: regex, django, django-forms, django-1.5, django-formwizard

I am using a form wizard for step-by-step forms in our django application.
Now the requirement is to restrict chinese characters in the form fields. I managed to get the regex but the problem is if I try to use that validator regex on email field it doesnt allow '@' symbol, and raises invalid flag.
Here is the regex I am using:

`restrict_chinese_characters_regex = RegexValidator(r'^[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF]*$', 'Chinese characters are restricted.')`

I am kind of lost to make it work also with email field to allow '@' symbol.
Any ideas please?

Comment: i think you need to define the pattern as unicode string like `u'^[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF@]*$'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you mean like `^[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF@]*$` this? No it didnt help.

Comment: did you see the `u` character before the pattern?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ok I skipped it at first, but tried again with `u` character, no it didnt help.